# Console output alignment for R-to-L languages (e.g arabic)

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem whenever I use `head()` or `table()` or similar commands. In the console output, column names and data are mismatched and wrongly aligned. I've already set `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "arabic")` to encode the arabic text, but still I can't get the correct output.

Here's an example:

```
    > city <- c("مدينة3", "مدينة2", "مدينة1")
    > pop<-c("1000", "2000", "3000") 
    > data <- data.frame(city, pop)
    > data
```

I get the output:

```
  city  pop
1 مدينة3 1000
2 مدينة2 2000
3 مدينة1 3000
```

As you can see **pop** column data are printed where the **city** data should be and vice versa.

How can I fix this?

---

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256  LC_CTYPE=Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with anything except for Rstudio scripting environment where it reads only from left to write, so after you write data correctly it switches itself, the easiest solution is to include the data on separate line to avoid texting confusion or read the data from file i.e. excel

```
city <- c("مدينة1",
          "مدينة2", 
          "مدينة3")

pop <- c("1000", "2000", "3000") 
data <- data.frame(city, pop)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however my problem is with the console output mismatch like I indicated in the output block.
I've tried using Rgui to no avail, same problems. I'm working on a large data set so it's even worse than this simple example.
This makes usage of R with R-to-L languages very difficult. I think it's a serious issue worth fixing.

Comment: I think if so then it is best to put your data in a file and then read it in Rstudio, this generally works just fine and you will not encounter this problem.